# Angular JS - Is there a way to pass the directive's attribute to the template

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

on the Page

```
<rn-text-edit rn-scope="profile.first_name"></rn-text-edit>
```

on the js

```
app.directive("rnTextEdit", function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        template:'<span>{{'+rn-scope+'}}</span>'
    }
});
```

I know I can replace the DOM and access the attribute through link. I wonder if there is a way of passing the directive's attribute to a template.

Comment: Can the directive use an isolate scope?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are just displaying the value:

```
<rn-text-edit rn-scope="{{profile.first_name}}"></rn-text-edit>
```

-

```
app.directive("rnTextEdit", function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        scope: {
            rnScope: '@'
        },
        template: '<span>{{rnScope}}</span>'
    }
});
```

If the directive needs to modify the value, you could use `'='` and skip the double curlies.

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PStHN/1/)

more info on scope and `'@'` in the [Angular Directives page](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive)

Comment: I think `@` would be more appropriate for this scenario, since the directive doesn't seem to need to alter the value.